# Linking the steps in a slider to images

Tags: jquery, image, uislider

I wish to display a series of map to show change over time. I have easily created a Jquery slider (a bar not an animation) with 10 steps and I would like to link each step to an image. I would prefer using the slider as it reinforces the idea of continuity. Buttons make each date and its map look like separate event, and an image slider does not fulfill my purpose either.

I have spent a lot (a lot) of time looking in books, tutorials, and on the web (especially Stackoverflow) and found nothing addressing this. I do not think I am using the wrong terminology in my searches, but I am beginning to wonder if it is even possible to do this in Jquery.

Thank you for any hint as to where to look or what to use.

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#hotelrooms). It can be modified to suit your needs:

```
$(function() {
    var maps = $( ".map" );
    var slider = $( "<div id='slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( select ).slider({
        min: 1,
        max: 6,
        range: "min",
        value: defaultValue,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            var map = $(maps[ui.value]); //This your map for the current index...
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How please? Maybe a very small example with 3 images? I want to do the same thing with weather map images. Scrub through them with a slider to see progress.